How to Exclude Specific Fields from Populated Documents in Mongoose Aggregation Pipelines?
I am using Mongoose aggregation pipelines with the $lookup stage to populate referenced documents. How can I exclude specific fields from the populated documents while retaining all other fields in the original document?
Example:
There is a Task schema that contains the 'case' field referenced from the Case schema. I want that, while querying the tasks using aggregation and lookup, I want to exclude some fields of the Case schema but include all fields of the Task schema.
(Include all field of Tasks, and only case_id, case_number from case (exclude rest all from case))
Task Schema
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    case: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Case"
    },
    task_field_2: {
      type: String
    },
    task_field_3: {
      type: String
    },
    .
    .
    .
    task_field_N: {
     type: String
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema);

Case Schema:
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const caseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    case_id: {
      type: Number,
      unique: true,
    },
    case_number: {
      type: String,
    },
    case_field_2: {
      type: String
    },
    case_field_3: {
      type: String
    },
    .
    .
    .
    case_field_N: {
     type: String
    }
})
module.exports = mongoose.model('Case', caseSchema);

I tried to do this, but it is excluding all fields of Tasks also.
$project: {
   "case.case_id": 1,
   "case.case_number": 1,
},


In your $project specify those fields you want to remove with 0. This will remove those unwanted field and maintain the existing field

Otherwise, you need to specify all the fields that you want to remain with "1"

@YongShun , As their are many number of fields, so writing all required fields or non required fields is not a good way
